# Sci-Fi movie where a hacker lives in a ruined church

Tags: story-identification, movie

This was a movie from recent years (2010 onward) about a dystopian future. The hero is some kind of unstable reject. He resides in a ruined church or cathedral and attempts to hack something or calculate something.

Someone from the organization he's trying to hack is supplying him with equipment which fills the church and supporting him. He may also be the villain.

At some point the church is raided by police or agents of the organization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*The Zero Theorem*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2333804/) (2013)

> A hugely talented but socially isolated computer operator is tasked by
> Management to prove the Zero Theorem: that the universe ends as
> nothing, rendering life meaningless. But meaning is what he already
> craves.